# php include causing jquery submit function to not work

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form. The form is in html I'm using jquery to pass the form to a php page for processing and json_encode to pass back the results to display to the user. If I try to add an incude xxx.php on the php page that jquery is submitting to it kills the whole thing.

**Here is how it lays out:
This is the main layout page and includes the form as you can see**

```
<form id="jq_forgot_password" class="forgot_password" action="" method="post" name="password_form">        

<?PHP include 'widgets/recover_pass.php'; ?>
</form>
```

**This is the content of the form itself:**

```
<!-- Password Recovery Form-->

    <div class="form_text">
    <p> 
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="recover_email" name="recover_email" placeholder="Enter your email address" class="field_boarder" value="" size="25px" maxlength="255"/> </p>

    <div class="login_button_container">
    <input name="login_button" type="submit" class="login_button" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**This is the jquery script that is posting the form data and preventing the default submit button from refreshing the page:**

```
  // Forgot Password Validation and Post Function

    $(function(){

        $("#jq_forgot_password").submit(function(e){

           e.preventDefault();  



            $.post("widgets/recover_pass_process.php", $("#jq_forgot_password").serialize(),

            function(data){



                if(data.email_check == 'invalid'){

                        $('div.message_error').hide();
                        $('div.message_success').hide();
                        $('div.message_error').fadeIn();
                        $('div.message_error').html("<div'> Sorry you must enter a valid e-mail address. Try again.</div>");

                } else {

                    $('div.message_error').hide();
                    $('form#jq_forgot_password').hide();
                    $('div.message_success').fadeIn();
                    $('div.message_success').html("<div'>You're Password has been sent to" + data.email + ". Thank you </div>");

                    }

            }, "json");

        });

        });
```

**This is the php file that the jquery submit function is submitting to:**

```
 <?php



    $email_check = '';

    $return_arr = array();

    if(filter_var($_POST['recover_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

       $email_check = 'valid';

    }

    else {

        $email_check = 'invalid';

    }



    $return_arr["email_check"] = $email_check;

    $return_arr["email"] = $_POST['recover_email'];


    echo json_encode($return_arr);

    ?>
```

**This all works fine BUT if I add an include statement at the top of the recover_pass_process.php like this:**

```
 <?php

    include 'func/user.func.php';

    $email_check = '';

    $return_arr = array();

    if(filter_var($_POST['recover_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

       $email_check = 'valid';

    }

    else {

        $email_check = 'invalid';

    }



    $return_arr["email_check"] = $email_check;

    $return_arr["email"] = $_POST['recover_email'];


    echo json_encode($return_arr);

    ?>
```

Then it all comes to a screeching halt even if the included file has nothing in it. Just the fact that I'm trying to include another file kills it.

What am I doing wrong???  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure the other file has nothing in it? It probably has a blank line, space, or Unicode byte order mark you can't see. That text would be sent before the json response, making the response no longer valid json. Have you attempted any debugging? Looked at the JavaScript console in your web browser for the error message?

Comment: the problem is not the include but the programmer.

Comment: the test include file I tried is absolutely empty it just has  <?php?> and the debug console has no errors. But shouldn't json_encode only be sending the ($return_arr) back? oh and RobertPitt thanks.. really... Super helpful.

Comment: Ok... I'm an idiot but thank you for looking at my question. The solution was stupid and simple I'm embarrassed to say.

My include statement was pointing to the incorrect directory. The recover_pass_process.php file was sitting in a widgets folder so I needed to add

include '../func/user.func.php';
and not

include 'func/user.func.php';
so that it would back up a directory to see the correct file.

I feel stupid but I thought I'd let you know that the code I have is working.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#jq_forgot_password").live("submit",function(e){

       e.preventDefault();  



        $.post("widgets/recover_pass_process.php", $("#jq_forgot_password").serialize(),

        function(data){



            if(data.email_check == 'invalid'){

                    $('div.message_error').hide();
                    $('div.message_success').hide();
                    $('div.message_error').fadeIn();
                    $('div.message_error').html("<div'> Sorry you must enter a valid e-mail address. Try again.</div>");

            } else {

                $('div.message_error').hide();
                $('form#jq_forgot_password').hide();
                $('div.message_success').fadeIn();
                $('div.message_success').html("<div'>You're Password has been sent to" + data.email + ". Thank you </div>");

                }

        }, "json");

    });
```

try this..